# MYSQL case then update

Tags: mysql

I am creating a MYSQL case, where i want to say:

if age in fieldname "age" = over 20 years old
then update the field "points" to 15 (example value)

It does not accept the "update" statement after the then. Is there another way to do it?
It is a "case" statement from dropdown boxes, so i cannot put too many "if else" statements.

Fieldnames are age, score:

```
SELECT `FieldName`, `FieldValue`, 
    CASE WHEN `FieldValue` = "over 20 years old" 
    THEN (UPDATE `table` 
    SET `FieldValue`= 15
    WHERE `FieldName` = 'points')    

When ...(if age less than 20, update points to 10)... 

    ELSE something else
    END 
FROM table where `FieldName` = 'age'
```

UPDATE,
Something is missing, it runs but not updating the prices:

```
UPDATE `TABLE` SET `FieldValue` = CASE 
WHEN `FieldValue` = 'over 20' THEN 5
When `FieldValue` = 'less than 20' THEN 10 
ELSE `FieldValue` = 3 
END WHERE`FieldName` = 'points'
```

Comment: That's not how you write an update statement and if you google mysql update with case you will find loads of examples.

Comment: Update itself is working, but not inside the "case"

Comment: Maybe so you but cannot conflate select and update like this.

Comment: why not just `UPDATE table SET points=15 WHERE age='over 20 years old'`? or I am misunderstood?

Comment: Yes, but there are many cases. This is why i want to use case statement, such as i would use a "switch" elsewhere.

Comment: Could you please add the complete code, like Drop down and how you prepare query based on that drop down value ?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
UPDATE table SET points=IF(age>20,15,10)
```

Comment: It should be a "switch" "case" expression, because i choose from dropdown boxes to insert to database. Not too many "if else"

Comment: @stsesn could you give example about your dropdown? is it from your application like `<select>` in html or what? what options are inside of the dropdown and what result do you expect from each select? I'll update my answer if I understand more about your need.